# Does Google Play Developer API provide "Query by order number" API?

Tags: android, google-play

I'd like to query user's order number (GPA.xxx) in inapp purchases in server side, does Google Play provider any similar APIs? I am searching for a long time on Google and API documents. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have the token that was provided (to the customer) when the order was originally placed, you can use [`Purchases.products:get`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get). Presumably you already know the "package name" and the "product ID".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I'd like to query user's purchase in server side by user's order number, not purchase token returned by Google Play in client.

Comment: I'm not going to tell you it can't be done, b/c the Google Play console can obviously generate a list of orders based on Google Play developer credentials, but I am unable to find documentation for the API they're using. You can see it hits this URL: `https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ordermanagement?account=...`